# What is the best practice for getting autofill browser data in react field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Basically, I'm using the onChange method for my input fields to get input data, but since chrome fill some fields on page load, how I can get these data along with using onChange method at the same time?

using refs and fetching data on initial useEffect() could be a solution. but I like to know is there any better solution which involves onChange or something like that?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it! simply by adding **name** attribute to the input field, react automatically triggers onChange method on autofill evet.